# How can I call a class from main class?

Tags: java, object, vector, constructor

- Define a class Passenger having the fields name (String), age (int), gender (char : M/F), weight (int)
- Define a class TrainCoach having the fields Passenger[] passengers
- Define the class Train and the functions in it. The class Train has the field Vector coaches.
  Given a Vector as input, create the object Train where each String[] is similar to the one that was given as input to TrainCoach above.

I am having trouble in calling the functions of Train class in main class?How can I call those methods?

**Passenger Class:**

```
 public class Passenger {
    String name;
    int age;
    char gender;
    int weight; 
    public Passenger(){}
        public Passenger(String data){
                String[] s=data.split(":");
                this.name=s[0];
                this.age=Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
                this.gender=s[2].charAt(0);
                this.weight=Integer.parseInt(s[3]);
        }
        public Passenger[] makePassenger(String[] input){
            Passenger[] passengers=new Passenger[input.length];
            for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
                passengers[i]=new Passenger(input[i]);
            }
            return passengers;
        }


}
```

**TrainCoach class:**

```
package Passenger;


public class TrainCoach {
    Passenger[] passengers;
    static char gender;
    public TrainCoach(){}
    public TrainCoach(Passenger[] passengers){
        this.passengers=passengers;
    }
    public TrainCoach(String[] data){
        Passenger[] passengers=new Passenger[data.length];
        for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            passengers[i]=new Passenger(data[i]);
        }
        this.passengers=passengers;
    }
    public static class PassengerTest{

        public static void main(String[] args){
            String[] str={"Amit Sharma:24:M:72","Rahul:12:M:55"};
            Passenger pass=new Passenger();
            Passenger[] passenger=pass.makePassenger(str);
            TrainCoach traincoach=new TrainCoach(passenger);
            int c=traincoach.numberOfPassengers();
            int d=traincoach.numberOfChildren();
            int b=traincoach.totalWeight();
            int a=traincoach.numberOf(gender);
            System.out.print(c+","+d+","+b+","+a);
        }
    }
    public int numberOfPassengers(){
        return this.passengers.length;
    }
    public int numberOfChildren(){
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<passengers.length;i++){
            if(passengers[i].age < 16){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    public int totalWeight(){
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<passengers.length;i++){
            sum+=passengers[i].weight;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    public int numberOf(char gender){
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<passengers.length;i++){
            if(passengers[i].gender=='M'){
                count++;
            }
            else if(passengers[i].gender=='F'){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

**Train class:**

```
package Passenger;

import java.util.Vector;

public class Train{

    Vector<TrainCoach>coaches;

    public Train(){}
    public Train(Vector<String[]> data){
        for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
            coaches.addElement(new TrainCoach(data.elementAt(i)));
        }
        this.coaches=coaches;
    }
    public int numberOfPassengers(){
        int numOfPassengersInTrain = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < coaches.size(); i++){
                numOfPassengersInTrain += this.coaches.elementAt(i).numberOfPassengers();
        }
        return(numOfPassengersInTrain);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can your write the Error msg ?!

Comment: Please point out exactly which line is failing and with what error?

Comment: Error-*Could not find or load main class passenger*... I am unable to link this with main class.

Comment: In which Class have you tried to create a Train object? What error are  you getting?

Comment: Are you trying to execute Passenger? (if so, you need a static Main(String[] args) method declared.)

Comment: I have written it above, the error I am getting.

Comment: Check your package statements and try to put all classes in the same directory with the same package statement

Comment: All classes are in same package "Passenger"

Comment: Class TrainCoach executes well but when I am trying to execute Train class it gives the error *Could not find or load main class passenger*

Comment: The class is called `Passenger`, not `passenger`.  Java class names are case-sensitive.  Are you sure you're not just accidentally telling Java to run a class that really doesn't exist (i.e. `passenger`)?

Comment: Sorry,I just wrote it wrong in the comment.It is Passenger in code.@Wyzard

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues with the code you've provided.

1. Your `Passenger` class does not have a package statement, but the other classes are located in `package Passenger`. Because of this, the classes referencing Passenger should actually not compile. Perhaps you just forgot the package statement when copy/pasting the code to stackoverflow? Anyway, to fix this, make sure that the `Passenger` has the same package as the other classes.

   Normally you could also solve this by importing the `Passenger` class in the other classes that reference it, but it is not possible to import a class when it does not have a package, so you need that package statement.
2. It is very confusing that you have the same name for a class and a package. You should at least name the package `passenger` with lower-case 'p' and the class `Passenger` with upper-case 'P'. This is the normal Java code standard.
3. I'm not quite sure what you're actually trying to do, but it seems to me that you are trying to execute the Passenger class; something like `java Passenger`. This will fail since there are no `main` method in the Passenger class. Whichever class you are using as entry point, that class needs a `main` method with the following signature:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   ```

   Also, remember that when the class gets a package name, you will need to include the package name when executing; i.e something like `java passenger.Passenger`.

Hope this helps you along the way.